# Как дождаться выполнения функции

Tags: swift, swiftui

Иммеется такой код:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            var s = RunQuery() //В функции RunQuery() выполняется запрос, после его выполнения запускается 
                               //функция Singleton.setParam(value: "test", key: "keyWord")
            if(Singleton.getParam(key: "keyWord")) {
                print("Yes")
            } else {
                print("No")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что когда в первый раз нажимаю на кнопку в функции не успевает выполниться запрос и записаться значение и поэтому выводится `No`. При повторном нажатии выводится `Yes`, так как значение уже записано с того раза. Как правильно сделать, что бы сперва отобразился `Yes`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу предложить использование колбеков, и вы сможете подцепиться к выполнению метода напрямую. Вот например:

```
func getBoolValue(number : Int, completion: (Bool)->()) {
    if number > 5 {
        completion(true)
    } else {
        completion(false)
    }
}

getBoolValue(number: 2) { (result) -> () in
    // do stuff with the result
    print(result)
}
```

вы же будете возвращать тип который вам нужен. Вот есть [примеры](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2016/02/15/fundamentals-of-callbacks-for-swift-developers/) как с этим можно работать. Если же речь идет о запросах, то стоит посмотреть в стороне асинхронности, чтобы не блокировать UI в ожиданиях.